# Center text on (x, y) with SVGKit for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, svg, svgkit

I'm generating an `SVG` from a `NSString*` on `iOS`. I can't center a text around a `(x, y)` coordinate. I've tried the following:

```
text-alignment="middle"  
text-anchor="middle" 
style="text-anchor:middle"
style="text-alignment:middle"
```

but I couldn't make it work.

Didn't find anything helpful on the webs either.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given your tag set, I assume you are using SVGKit (https://github.com/SVGKit) to do your rendering?  It appears from searching their source repo, that they do not support the text-anchor property.  So more than likely, that will be your problem.

Comment: according to the tags and the question's title lol anyway I saw one [example where they used it](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/blob/master/Demo-Samples/SVG/Text.svg) that's why I got confused..